# Google Analytics usage disclosure in privacy policy

Tags: google-analytics, terms-of-use, privacy-policy

This "[Google Privacy Center](http://www.google.com/intl/en/analytics/privacyoverview.html)" states that:

> All website owners using Google Analytics are required to have a
>   privacy policy that fully discloses the use of Google Analytics.

At the [Google Analytics TOS](http://www.google.com/intl/en/analytics/tos.html), there doesn't seem to be this requirement.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google just changed its privacy policies (so there might still be inconsistencies). here's an email I received from google a few days ago:

---

Dear Google user,

We're getting rid of over 60 different privacy policies across Google and replacing them with one that's a lot shorter and easier to read. Our new policy covers multiple products and features, reflecting our desire to create one beautifully simple and intuitive experience across Google.

We believe this stuff matters, so please take a few minutes to read our updated Privacy Policy and Terms of Service at http://www.google.com/policies. These changes will take effect on March 1, 2012.

Comment: Both the TOS and the Privacy Ceneter show ©2011 meaning that they haven't been updated since last year. Additionally, comparing to older the TOS through archive.org, it hasn't really changed other than upping 5m to 10m pageviews/month. This is unrelated to their privacy policy change.

Comment: like I said, the link to "privacy overview" that you posted is no longer valid. 1. http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/ states that google got rid of all 60 separate PP and composed 1 general policy for all their products. 2. if you'll search the link that you posted  - you'll see that google does not link to it anymore! (the only link you'll find on google servers is from one of the forums).

Comment: Google links to the 2011 Analytics "Google Privacy Center" from their NEW combined [Privacy Policy Advertising FAQ](http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/ads/#toc-analytics) with a "Learn more about the Google Analytics Opt-out Browser Add-on and other Google Analytics privacy information." anchor.

Answer (score 2):

Every website using Google Analytics is required to provide a privacy policy. You can generate a Google Analytics compliant privacy policy with iubenda: http://www.iubenda.com

(I'm the founder ;) )

Comment: Please [disclose your affiliation](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) when promoting your own products.

Comment: You are completely right, I always do it, forgotten this time, sorry :'(